# WPF Canvas Add img to Canvas give unnecessary magin

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, margin

Hi when i try to put image to canvas using Label as container, I got TOP + 4 Left + 4 out of nowhere. I did send the image to = 0 left = 0 and got it on top=4 left = 4);
Please Help. thx

XAML:

```
<Grid   >

    <Canvas Name="TWCanvas"  Margin="0,0,0,0" Height="1000" Width="1200"/>
</Grid>
```

Code:

```
Public void PutImg(string path)
    {
        Image img = new Image();
        img.Width = 100;
        img.Height = 100;
        img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(path, UriKind.Relative));
        img.Stretch = Stretch.Fill;
        Label lbl = new Label();
        lbl.Content = img;
        lbl.Margin = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);

        Canvas.SetLeft(lbl, 0);
        Canvas.SetTop(lbl, 0);

        TWCanvas.Children.Add(lbl);

    }
```

Comment: Try using snoop utility to see what is causing the margin/padding issue

Comment: @Krishna Have you seen that there is already an answer that explains the observed behaviour?

Comment: @Clemens I saw that, Please do not misunderstand me though. I was only suggesting to use snoop as the tool helps me a lot in fixing problems like these rather than coming to SO for them. I am happy to delete my comment if you want :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see is the Label's `Padding` (an internal margin). Either set it to zero

```
lbl.Padding = new Thickness();
```

or drop the (apparently redundant) Label control and add the Image directly to your Canvas:

```
Canvas.SetLeft(img, 0);
Canvas.SetTop(img, 0);
TWCanvas.Children.Add(img);
```